# javax print not actually printing anything

Tags: java, printing

Desperately trying to print a document using the following code. A document is being added to the printer queue but nothing actually comes out of the printer.

```
    PrintService defaultService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    PrintService printService[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream("hello world!\f".getBytes("UTF8"));

    PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    pras.add(new Copies(1));

    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    PrintService service = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 200, 200, printService, defaultService, flavor, pras);
    DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

    DocAttributeSet das = new HashDocAttributeSet();
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(stream, flavor, das);

    PrintJobWatcher pjw = new PrintJobWatcher(job);
    job.print(doc, pras);
    pjw.waitForDone();
```

The print dialog I get shows the correct default printer (as below), plus the list of other available printers:

[image: printer dialog]

If I change the printer to "Microsoft print to PDF", I get an empty (0kb) pdf. Interestingly, if I tick "Print to File" I get a prn file with the correct contents ("hello world!FF").

What am I missing?

Comment: I have excactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?